# Fabricators not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3, fabrication-gem

I get an empty array while trying to use fabricators in my specs.  My guess is that the fabricator file has not loaded.  If I load the fabricator file after RSpec's initialization then a `Fabrication::DuplicateFabricatorError` is raised.  Here's my setup:

- rails 4.1.4
- rspec-core 3.1.5
- rspec-rails 3.1.0
- fabrication 2.11.3

.

```
# config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework      :rspec, fixture: true
  g.fixture_replacement :fabrication, dir: "spec/fabricators"
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fabricators"
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Here's the code that should be working but isn't:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

# spec/fabricators/user_fabricator.rb
Fabricator(:user) do
  email                 { Faker::Internet.email }
  password              "password"
  password_confirmation "password"
end

# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  before :each do
    @user = Fabricator(:user)
    #=> []
  end

  it "has an email" do
    expect(@user.email).to be_a(String)
    expect(@user.email.length).to be > 0
  end
end
```

After getting an empty array returned for my fabricator, I get this error when running specs: `undefined method 'email' for []:Array`.  I expect to get a passing spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues here as far as I can see. The first is that you do not need this line in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fabricators"
```

The second is that you are calling `Fabricator` instead of `Fabricate` in the `before` block of your spec. `Fabricator` is used to declare definitions and `Fabricate` is used to actually create an object.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  My spec is passing with those two changes.  I'm feeling silly for missing the spelling difference but the word choice makes a lot of sense now that you mention it.